# Is it possible to get the hardware information with php or javascript?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the hardware details with php script.Also is it possible to check whether a pen drive or something is connected to the pc via php script.
So when users loads the web page it should say , "Pendrive is connected to your computer"?
Is it possible?

Please see this link.How it works.
http://linfo.sourceforge.net/demo/

Comment: PHP server side script ..how come it will detect your HARDWARE things

Comment: http://linfo.sourceforge.net/demo/ is showing the space details, I doubt whether it is a php alone application or not.

Comment: linfo.sourceforge.net/demo < is showing information about the server NOT the client.

Comment: You can use JavaScript, but you don't get all information you want.

Comment: thanks i understand the scenario, it was server config that linfo.sourceforge.net/demo is showing

Answer (score 2):

With PHP the answer is NO. PHP run on server-side...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can use PHP to get OS hardware information via Linfo library.

Here is an example of the PHP script to show CPU info:

```
<?php
  $linfo = new \Linfo\Linfo;
  $parser = $linfo->getParser();
  var_dump($parser->getCPU());
?>
```

Here is the source code of Linfo library: https://github.com/jrgp/linfo

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. It would be far better to provide an example of _Linfo_ or at least quote the relevant parts of the link (in case the link goes down etc)

Answer (score 0):

What "hardware details"? What level of detail do you want? PHP generally runs serverside, when users view a webpage php does not run locally on their PC. This is not possible via JavaScript. There are security implications in this concept. Would you want any webpage to be able to find out what's conneccted to your computer, and what the spec of the machine is?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no,you won't be able to get things like RAM, HDD space, etc... and even what you can get can easily be spoofed.  So the short answer is no, you can't do that with php.  You would need to make and have the user download and run something on their computer (like a java applet or activeX control) that can access that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear: Javascript is **always** executed on client-side in the users browser. It does **not** have access to any hardware, mostly for security reasons. Therefore it's not possible to do that in Javascript.

PHP is executed **purely** on the server, and it does have (limited by some restrictions) access to the hardware of the server - but in no way it has access to the hardware of a users computer.

Therefore no, it's not possible to do that. The only way I can think of is using ActiveX plugins or a browser addon.

Comment: Not true. nodejs is JavaScript on server side. And you can use (mostly HTML5) APIs to access (some) hardware. See my answer.

Comment: @Matjaz Lipus: While you are right that there are Javascript frameworks running on servers as well (or even acting as such) it doesn't change the fact that, in a webpage environment, Javascript is executed only on the client computer. And it does not have access to any hardware unless this functionality is explicitly exposed through the browser. However that is highly limited and nowhere near to the information shown in the example link in the original question - for good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Not with code that runs on server.

But with JavaScript run on client you can use some hardware features. For example camera, microphone, gamepads... See [www.gamepadjs.com](http://www.gamepadjs.com) for example.

Comment: Have you seen the link i posted.It gathers data how is it working?

Comment: @ABHINAND V NAIR: Your example shows the hardware details of the **server** it's running on (that's done using PHP). There is _no way_ to get access to this data about a visitors computer using PHP or Javascript!