# How to get computer hardware information of the server using PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I want to know the hardware information of the server using php such as

> 1) Motherboard serial number, or/and
>
> 2) Harddisk serial number (Hardware UUID), or/and
>
> 3) Memory (RAM) serial number, or/and
>
> 4) Connected Pen Drive serial number, or/and
>
> 5) Mac Address (I think it is not available on every computer)

I know that it is directly not possible, is there any apache module or php extension available for this purpose or is it possible that we can develop our own module/extension easily?

My motive is to uniquely identify the server using php code by finding its hardware information.

Note : Apache/PHP will be installed on windows computer without internet connection. So the php application will run on the localhost only.

Comment: Not sure about PHP, but you will be able to get this info using Perl.

Comment: _is it possible that we can develop our own module/extension easily?_ Possible? Of course. Easy? Depends on your knowledge and experience

Comment: @The Blue Dog, where can I find that perl script, do you know anyone? I possibly can think executing perl script inside php code.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878666/is-it-possible-to-get-the-hardware-information-with-php-or-javascript

Comment: @Anticom, the url you gave is asking about "client's" info but I am asking for "server's" info on which apache/php is installed.

Comment: My bad. Think that might be hard to do since it depends on the platform.

Comment: I am ok with only windows platform, "xp/win7/win8"