# How to retrive hardware details using a programming language?

Tags: java, javascript, php, applet, hardware

I want to retrieve the following things from the user's desktop when the user uses logs into my website:

1) Mother Board Serial Number
2) Hard Disk Serial Number
3) CPU Serial Number

Now I am confused and not sure which way to go.

I cannot use Javascript because it will not provide these details because of security reasons. 
I cannot use php because php runs on server side and not client side.

So last option is using Java Applets. As soon as the user logs in, the applet will be downloaded. When the user runs the applets, it will retrieve the necessary information. But I dont want to be using this because applets are obsolete these days and nobody uses them.

So is there any method in which I find find the user's hardware details without using Java Applets.

Comment: **Of course they aren't available.** Don't you think such information shouldn't be available to untrusted code?

Comment: possible [dublicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878666/is-it-possible-to-get-the-hardware-information-with-php-or-javascript)

Comment: Btw, I'd guess that applets have similar security restrictions and as Adriano said, I'd not want a website to read that information from _my_ machine.

Comment: Just out of interest: _why_ should that data be displayed? What would be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Using Java to get os level system Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information) will get you started in right direction.
2. [Finding Operating System Information](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml)
3. [How to get System Information using Java](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking)

Comment: An applet will run in a sandbox, almost noone would share personal information to untrusted code...